# How do I get past a VPN lock screen as I've never entered a password?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s

I downloaded Private Internet Access vpn to a Nexus S which also had Tor installed. Tor asked did I want to set up a VPN. I said yes. Nexus S vpn dialogue came up. I decided no and hit the back button to return to Tor. Went to front door to answer a knock with the phone in my hand.

Looked at the phone and saw a lock screen saying emergency calls only with a cursor blinking at me. Tried the random five wrong passwords with no result or no dialogue. End result no way back to the phone. Dont want a factory reset n losing my data. Ice Cream Sandwich runs (ran !) on the phone. Q: POssible hack ? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely wipe your phone from https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager and that will remove the lock, sorry for your luck.

- Edit: Looks like you can replace the lock from there using the lock feature there too, might be useful to you, to avoid wiping.